# Create with has_many relationship generate the error "Object must exist" even if it exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

My controller:

```
def buy_item
  @item = ItemShopItem.find(params[:item_id])
  @new_item = @account.items.create(vnum: @item.vnum, count: @item.amount)
  puts @new_item.errors.full_messages
end
```

Account model:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

Item model

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'player.item'

  belongs_to :account, primary_key: 'owner_id'

  before_create :set_item_position

  private

  def set_item_position
    position = select(:pos).where(owner_id: self.account.id).order('id desc').first.pos + 1
    self.pos = position
  end
end
```

The controller gives me this error even if the accout exists:

```
Account must exist
```

Obviously the account exist!

**UPDATE**

@account.byebug

```
Account must exist

Return value is: nil

[10, 19] in blablabla/item_shop_controller.rb
   10:     @account = Account.first
   11:     @item = ItemShopItem.find(params[:item_id])
   12:     @new_item = @account.items.create(vnum: @item.vnum, count: @item.amount)
   13:     puts @new_item.errors.full_messages
   14:     puts @account.byebug
=> 15:   end
```

@account.inspect

```
#<Account id: 1, login: "test", password: "*898425FBB710DA05B19D718FB320796E207FDB5F", real_name: "", social_id: "1234567", email: ....">
```

Answer (score 0):

@account refers to an instance of your Account model; instances are created from the model (Account.create). Since you're trying to create an @account, you should instead say @new_item = Account.create(vnum: @item.vnum, count: @item.amount), otherwise it thinks you're trying to use a nonexistent @account to create your variable instead of instantiating the Account model.

Comment: I'm not creating an account but I'm creating a new Item associated to an account. Item is a model and it belongs to account. Account has many items. The variable @account does exist in the rest of the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the object `@account` here it is NIL.

So when you are trying to apply a create query through `@account` with relation `has_many :items` through call  `@account.items`, it is not finding any account to associate the `sql call` with.

If there is no count how will Activerecord associate it with finding items.

Just to give it a go, in start of your method use

```
@account= Account.first
```

and then check.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply but I'm still getting the same error. However, @account does exist.

Comment: can you share `@account` value( partially) just before your create command in `buy_item` method. you can use `byebug` and check value of `@account`. Also share full error code

Comment: I've have update the main post with account.byebug and account.inspect. The first one says that it doesn't exist, while the second says that it exist. I'm getting confused now

Comment: I think I get the error, your item create calls a `before_create` method which requires `self.account.id`  which is null at the time of creation of new item object. Better use it in a `after_save` call

Comment: I removed that function but the error remains the  same. If I create a new item with item = Item.create(owner_id: account.id, ....) it works. But if I create it through account.item.create(), it doesn't work